# Hibernate save not populating child field

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I've got a hibernate entity Item that has a one-to-one relationship with another entity Image. I'm using JpaRepository to fetch the entities from the database. I've defined this relationship in Item like this:

```
    @Column(name = "image_id")
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    private UUID imageId;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "image_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Image image;
```

If I do the following:

```
Image image = new Image();
imageRepository.save(image);

Item item = new Item();
item.setImageId(image.getImageId());
Item savedItem = itemRepository.save(item);

assertNotNull(savedItem.getImage());
```

This assert fails.

If I do this instead:

```
Image image = new Image();
imageRepository.save(image);

Item item = new Item();
item.setImageId(image.getImageId());
itemRepository.save(item);
Item savedItem = itemRepository.findById(item.getItemId());

assertNotNull(savedItem.getImage());
```

the assert passes.

I thought hibernate would populate the item based on the id during the save? Why do I only get Item populated when I call a find after? Is there a way to get the return from save to have a populated item?

It just feels weird to have to do a find immediately after the save despite the save returning the entity.